# Need to be able to draw with only one finger (Xamarin.Forms, SkiaSharp)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I have an intermittent error (System.ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 1') when I draw with multiple fingers. I found out that it is related to the enabled MIUI optimization on my device. I would like everything to work correctly even when optimization is enabled, so I want the program to only recognize one touch at a time.

**PS:** I need the system to recognize only one touch at a time on this page.

My code:

**FingetPaintPolyline.cs:**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using SkiaSharp;

namespace ToothScan.Views
{
    class FingerPaintPolyline
    {
        public FingerPaintPolyline()
        {
            Path = new SKPath();
        }

    public SKPath Path { get; set; }

    public Color StrokeColor { get; set; }

    public float StrokeWidth { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**FingetPaintPage.xaml.cs:**

```
using SkiaSharp;
using SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using TouchTracking;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace ToothScan.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class FingerPaintPage : ContentPage
    {
        Dictionary<long, FingerPaintPolyline> inProgressPolylines = new Dictionary<long, FingerPaintPolyline>();
        List<FingerPaintPolyline> completedPolylines = new List<FingerPaintPolyline>();
    SKPaint paint = new SKPaint
    {
        Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
        StrokeCap = SKStrokeCap.Round,
        StrokeJoin = SKStrokeJoin.Round
    };
    public FingerPaintPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        completedPolylines.Clear();
    }
    void OnClearButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        completedPolylines.Clear();
        canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
    }

    void OnTouchEffectAction(object sender, TouchActionEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.Type)
        {
            case TouchActionType.Pressed:
                if (!inProgressPolylines.ContainsKey(args.Id))
                {
                    Color strokeColor = (Color)typeof(Color).GetRuntimeField(colorPicker.Items[colorPicker.SelectedIndex]).GetValue(null);
                    float strokeWidth = ConvertToPixel(new float[] { 1, 2, 5, 10, 20 }[widthPicker.SelectedIndex]);
                    colorPicker.BackgroundColor = strokeColor;
                    widthPicker.BackgroundColor = strokeColor;

                    FingerPaintPolyline polyline = new FingerPaintPolyline
                    {
                        StrokeColor = strokeColor,
                        StrokeWidth = strokeWidth
                    };
                    polyline.Path.MoveTo(ConvertToPixel(args.Location));
                    if(!inProgressPolylines.ContainsKey(args.Id))
                    {
                        inProgressPolylines.Add(args.Id, polyline);
                        canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                    }
                }
                break;

            case TouchActionType.Moved:
                if (inProgressPolylines.ContainsKey(args.Id))
                {
                    FingerPaintPolyline polyline = inProgressPolylines[args.Id];
                    try
                    {
                        polyline.Path.LineTo(ConvertToPixel(args.Location));
                        canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
                break;

            case TouchActionType.Released:
                if (inProgressPolylines.ContainsKey(args.Id))
                {
                    if (!completedPolylines.Contains(inProgressPolylines[args.Id]))
                    {
                        completedPolylines.Add(inProgressPolylines[args.Id]);
                    }
                    inProgressPolylines.Remove(args.Id);
                    canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                }
                break;

            case TouchActionType.Cancelled:
                if (inProgressPolylines.ContainsKey(args.Id))
                {
                    inProgressPolylines.Remove(args.Id);
                    canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    {
        SKCanvas canvas = args.Surface.Canvas;
        canvas.Clear();

        foreach (FingerPaintPolyline polyline in completedPolylines)
        {
            paint.Color = polyline.StrokeColor.ToSKColor();
            paint.StrokeWidth = polyline.StrokeWidth;
            canvas.DrawPath(polyline.Path, paint);
        }

        foreach (FingerPaintPolyline polyline in inProgressPolylines.Values)
        {
            paint.Color = polyline.StrokeColor.ToSKColor();
            paint.StrokeWidth = polyline.StrokeWidth;
            canvas.DrawPath(polyline.Path, paint);
        }
    }

    SKPoint ConvertToPixel(TouchTrackingPoint pt)
    {
        return new SKPoint((float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Width * pt.X / canvasView.Width),
                           (float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Height * pt.Y / canvasView.Height));
    }

    float ConvertToPixel(float fl)
    {
        return (float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Width * fl / canvasView.Width);
    }
    }
}
```

**FingetPaintPage.xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Forms"
             xmlns:tt="clr-namespace:TouchTracking.Forms;assembly=TouchTracking.Forms"
             x:Class="ToothScan.Views.FingerPaintPage"
             Title="Drawing"
             BackgroundColor="Gainsboro"
             Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Picker x:Name="colorPicker"
            Title="Color"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Margin="10"
            BackgroundColor="DarkGray"
            FontSize="15"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
        <Picker.Items>
            <x:String>Red</x:String>
            <x:String>Green</x:String>
            <x:String>Blue</x:String>
            <x:String>Aqua</x:String>
            <x:String>Fuchsia</x:String>
            <x:String>Yellow</x:String>
            <x:String>Black</x:String>
            <x:String>Gray</x:String>
            <x:String>White</x:String>
        </Picker.Items>

        <Picker.SelectedIndex>
            0
        </Picker.SelectedIndex>
    </Picker>
    <Picker x:Name="widthPicker"
            Title="Width"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="10"
            BackgroundColor="DarkGray"
            FontSize="15"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
        <Picker.Items>
            <x:String>Thin (1 px)</x:String>
            <x:String>Thinish (2 px)</x:String>
            <x:String>Medium (5 px)</x:String>
            <x:String>Thickish (10 px)</x:String>
            <x:String>Thick (20 px)</x:String>
        </Picker.Items>

        <Picker.SelectedIndex>
            0
        </Picker.SelectedIndex>
    </Picker>

    <Button Text="Clear"
            x:Name="ClearBtn"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="2"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            Clicked="OnClearButtonClicked"
            Margin="10"/>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1"
          Grid.Column="0"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="3">

        <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView"
                           PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface"/>
        <Grid.Effects>
            <tt:TouchEffect Capture="True"
                            TouchAction="OnTouchEffectAction"/>
        </Grid.Effects>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: you need to look at `tt:TouchEffect` and see if this is supported, or modify it if it isn't

Comment: @Jason Thanks for the answer, but I would like to clarify that the program works, but in rare cases it gives an error, as far as I understand, MIUI optimization severely limits background processes, which makes drawing with several fingers problematic.

Comment: I don't understand how that is relevant to my comment.  You want to disable multiple touches, then you need to look into how TouchEffect is implemented.

Comment: An alternative solution is to write platform-specific code. Start at [Touch in Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/touch/touch-in-android), and read sections through page "Multi-Touch Finger Tracking", which should give some clue how to disable the "multi" part. You'd write android code in a custom renderer on a subclass of either SKCanvasView or some view or layout wrapping that. (Its been years since I dealt directly with Android touch.)